# Google analytics track event Aborting hit error

Tags: events, google-analytics, onclick

I'm trying to add event tracking in a tabs navigation...
so onclick of the tabs i have something like that:

```
onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Tabs', 'Click', 'TabName']);"
```

I have also added GA Debug add-on in chrome.

Every time i'm clicking i'm getting this in the console:

> Track Event
>
> ga_debug.js:24 User has been sampled out. Aborting hit.

Does anyone know why I'm getting this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check **setSampleRate** parameter in your GA configuration. This probably cause your problem, because script cancel hit if Math.random value is lower than setter sample rate.

It is not a bug. If you need to test some configuration, set it for 100 during test and on production environment set it back to your desired value.

Comment: Hi and thanks for your answer. At the moment this is set to 1. I suppose that if i change it to 100 and then change it back to 1 for production then i'm going to have the same 'error' on prod and then my event will not be tracked? What are the implications of setting that 100 in prod?

Comment: On huge websites sending milions hits per day is good to have manual sampling enabled, so if you have sample rate 50 (%), each second hit will be counted. It is normal to have 100 on production. Only if you need to set it lower, do it.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  This is fixing my issue.